# Two distinct numbers have the same number of digits and sum of digits. Can one be a multiple of the other?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

a and b are two numbers having the same number of digits and same sum of digits (=28). Can one be a multiple of the other? a is not equal to b.

I tried writing a =a1a2...an and b=b1b2...bn (ai,bi are digits) as two n-digit numbers and Σai=Σbi=28.
I tried to think of a way to write a=kb or prove a condraction but couldn't proceed.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$a \mod 9 \equiv 1$
$b \mod 9 \equiv 1$
$2a \mod 9 \equiv 2$

Hence: $b \neq 2a$

Comment: @lulu: "the sum of the digits being 28" gave it away for me: it you sum the digits, and sum that again, and again, ... unti you only have one digit, then that digit is the rest while dividing by $9$ (understanding $9$ as $0$, obviously). Starting from that, $28 => 10 => 1$ makes the whole question trivial, as you say :-)

Comment: Note that being a multiple is not restricted to just $b = 2a$. You'd want $ b \neq ka$ with $k \leq 9, a \neq kb$. That is where "same number of digits" comes in (which you haven't used so far).

Answer (score 1):

As in the original post, suppose:
$$a=\overline{a_1a_2a_3...a_n}$$
$$b=\overline{b_1b_2b_3...b_n}$$

It goes to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i=28$, which is given. If the sum of digits of a number is $27$, that would mean the number is divisible by $9$. Hence, if the sum of digits of a number is $28$ then the number should be one more than a multiple of $9$.
$$a\equiv1\mod9$$
$$b\equiv1\mod9$$
We are now asked to verify if $b$ is a multiple of $a$. Now,
$$2a\equiv2\mod9$$$$3a\equiv3\mod9$$$$4a\equiv4\mod9$$and so on, until $9a\equiv0\mod9$. Notice how in $\mod9$, none of the values $2a,3a,4a,...,9a$ are equal to $b$, since $b\equiv1\mod9$.
Coming to $10a$. We see that $10a\equiv1\mod9$. So $10a\stackrel{?}{=}b$.

However, if $b$ is equal to $10a$, then $b$ will have $n+1$ digits, as:
$b=10a=\overline{a_1a_2a_3...a_n0}$. A similar logic can apply to show why $b=19a$, $28a$, and so on will also give $b$ more than $n$ digits.

This contradicts the information given, since if $b$ were a multiple of $a$, satisfying the required conditions, it will never have the same number of digits as $a$. Hence, one **cannot** be a multiple of the other.

Answer (score -1):

Some partial solutions
that don't satisfy
all the conditions.

These two pairs add to 9, so three concatenated add to 27.

$36$ and $72$

$45$ and $90$

Seven copies of 04 and 40
add to 28
but don't have
the same number of digits.

Comment: -1 Sorry, I have no idea what you're doing here. Is this just thinking-out-loud space? You got an upvote, so I downvoted to bring it back to 0 trying to favor the other solution even though it's still incomplete.

Comment: Just sharing some ideas that might be added to.